# Automatically assigning new Drupal users to Organic Group based on email address

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm hoping to have users who sign up for an account on a Drupal 7 site automatically added to a particular Organic Group based on their email address domain. For example, user@company1.com would be added to the Company1 OG, user@company2.com would be added to the Company2 OG, etc. I'm trying to figure out if anyone has managed to do this without a custom modules, e.g. using Rules and maybe some OG add-on.

Comment: did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, and I ended up moving to a different department in the meantime. Sorry...

Comment: After coming back around to this same problem - there still does not appear to be an existing module that does this. Ideally, you'd have a mapping of email address domains to organic groups, and then do the assignment at account creation time, maybe via `hook_user_insert`.